# What is $\int \ (\frac{d}{dt} X, N\times X) dt$, which is a length of dual curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $N:[0,l]\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is a simple closed curve in some open hemisphere in a unit sphere (maybe $|N'(t)|\neq 1$) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then assume that $X$ is unit vector field along $N$ in the sphere.

> Problem : Then the quantity $$ \int_0^l \ \bigg( \frac{d}{dt} X(t), N\times X\bigg)\ dt\ \ast$$ is independent of the vector field $X$ where $(\ ,\ )$ is an inner product and $\times$ is a cross product.

If $X = N\times \frac{N'}{|N'|}$ which is a dual curve of the curve $N$, then $\ast$ is equal to the length of the curve $X$ in unit sphere (by a long direct computation).

Comment: “Then $X$is a unit vector field …”? The English makes no sense. If you assume $X$ is normal to the curve, then this looks like the definition of total twist.

Answer (score 1):

We define $\alpha(s)=N\circ t (s)$ s.t.
$|\alpha'(s)|=1$ i.e. $\alpha :[0,L]\rightarrow_t
[0,l]\rightarrow_N\mathbb{S}^2$ and $t'(s) =\frac{1}{|N'(t)|}$.

Here $$  \int_0^l\ (\frac{d}{dt}X, N\times X) dt = \int_0^L\
(\frac{d}{dt}X, \alpha\times X)t'(s) ds =\int_0^L \ (\frac{d}{ds}
X,\alpha\times X)\ ds$$

Define $B =\alpha\times \alpha'$ so that for some $a$,

$$X=\cos\ a \alpha' + \sin\ a B $$

Hence $$ \alpha\times X = \cos\ a B+\sin\ a (-\alpha') $$

Hence \begin{align*} \\&\int_0^L\ (\frac{d}{ds} X,\alpha\times X)\ ds\\ &=\int_0^L\ \bigg(
(-\sin\ a \alpha' +\cos a B)a' +\cos\ a\alpha '' +\sin\ a B' , \cos\
a B -\sin\ a \alpha'\bigg)\ ds
\\&=\int_0^L\ a' + (\alpha'',B)\ ds \\&= \int_0^L\ (\alpha'',\alpha\times\alpha ') ds
\end{align*}